# How to export an array inside a hashtable to CSV?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a hashtable containing arrays of strings as values such as

```
Name                      Value
----                      -----
ID1                       {SN1,IN1}
ID2                       {SN2,IN2}
ID3                       {SN3,IN3}
ID4                       {SN4,IN4}        
...                       ...
```

with `SN#` and `IN#` being strings.

I want to export this hashtable to a CSV file with this format:

```
 SN | IN
---------
SN1 | IN1
SN2 | IN2
SN3 | IN3
SN4 | IN4
... and so on.
```

Answer (score 3):

Build custom objects from each nested array, then export those to a CSV:

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'SN' = $_.Value[0]
        'IN' = $_.Value[1]
    }
} | Select-Object SN, IN | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: hey Ansgar! thank you each time for helping me!! your code is great. When i opened the csv file though, some of the INs were missing. Do you know why?

Comment: @SuinYun I would need to see your original data for that.

Comment: i printed out the hashtable values and they print with blank lines. so there should be 200 rows without any blanks, but like 350 rows with blank rows are printed. I think it has to do it with maybe? I don't understand why the dictionary is printing out blank lines though

Comment: is there a way we can use a regular forloop with a counter instead of a forEach loop? i think that would solve the issue.

Comment: because i think i need to access the values in each column by doing .values.get(0).get($n)

Comment: @SuinYun I fail to see how using a `for` loop would solve the issue unless your data is fundamentally different from what you showed in your question. Please show a representative sample of your input as well as desired and actual output from that input.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$objects = foreach($ID in $hashtable.Keys){
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    ID = $ID
    SN = @($hashtable[$ID] |Where {$_ -like 'SN*'}) -join ','
    IN = @($hashtable[$ID] |Where {$_ -like 'IN*'}) -join ','
  }
}

$objects |Export-Csv path\to\my.csv
```